# What does the tf_exported_symbols.lds do

Tags: tensorflow

I'm learning bazel and tensorflow, and when I check the tensorflow code I find this file: `https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tf_version_script.lds`

So what does this file actually do?

Comment: I think you may be installing TensorFlow from the wrong repository. Check out the [official github repository](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/) and/or the official [installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/).

Comment: @AkshayAgrawal Thanks for the reply, I just update the link. I want to know the purpose of that file. Installation is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `tf_exported_symbols.lds` limits the symbols that are visible in the shared object `_pywrap_tensorflow.so`, in order to prevent other packages from accidentally linking against symbols internal to TensorFlow.

For more context, see [this commit](https://github.com/qbx2/tensorflow/commit/f2f9322db34d0d500bff2d7ac812c2daf53d4d79) that introduced the file, and [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1924) that triggered the creation of said commit.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found that file is used in BUILD with `-exported_symbols_list`, than I find this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/DynamicLibraryDesignGuidelines.html

Comment: Yes, my score is too low to upvote it, just click the accept it, thanks!